# Smoothing with fda package when time grids differ

Tags: r, functional-data-analysis

In fda package, function smooth.basis is used to construct a functional data object by smoothing data using a roughness penalty.
The usage can be found [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/fda/docs/smooth.basis).

```
smooth.basis(argvals=1:n, y, fdParobj, wtvec=NULL, fdnames=NULL,
             covariates=NULL, method="chol", dfscale=1, returnMatrix=FALSE)
```

In the documentation, it said

> ***argvals:*** Argument values can even vary from one variable to another, in which
>   case they are input as an array with dimensions corresponding to
>   observation points, curves and variables, respectively. Note, however,
>   that the number of observation points per curve and per variable may
>   NOT vary. If it does, then curves and variables must be smoothed
>   individually rather than by a single call to this function.

**My question is how to set it up to use the function when we have subjects with different number of observations observed at different time series.**

For example, subject 1 has 10 observations at time week 1 to week 10, but subject 2 has only 5 observations at week 1.5, week 2.5, week 3.5, week 4.5, week 5.5.

Do I need to use the same basis system like b-spline to smooth two curves to make them comparable or consistent? Can anyone give me some examples to illustrate it?